# Integrate Map/Reducer and Java Project Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, integration, hadoop-plugins

I have a Java Project & **Map/Reducer** Project in **eclipse** Workspace, I want to use a class file of Map/Reducer Project from java project to perform computation, I am new to **Apache Hadoop & Map/Reducer** thing, please Suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a hadoop project is just like a Java project (and it probably is); right click on the other project in the package explorer, select properties, and then choose java build path. After that, click on the projects tab and select the add button. A dialog box should come up, and you should be able to select your hadoop project.

Both projects must be in the workspace, of course.